# Is there a way to copy formatting from a multi-select dropdown list in Excel through VBA code which performs a function similar to VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I currently have VBA code which is used to allow multiple different entries within a dropdown list to be clicked one after another and have each entry within the same cell in a separate line that is spaced out with a "spacer" as defined as "DelimiterType = vbCrLf" within the VBA code. Without the code, if a user were to click on Option A in the dropdown, the cell would populate with Option A. If the user were to then click on Option B in the dropdown, the cell would erase itself and populate it with Option B such that Option B is the only Option within the cell. With the code, the same process would populate the cell with both Option A and Option B on separate lines within the same cell, spaced out by a spacer.

The issue is that when using the generic VLOOKUP formula built into Excel, the formatting of the original cell is not copied: the "spacer" is not copied at all, and as a result the original cell is copied but with all the selected options pasted onto a single line instead of on separate lines spaced apart by the Delimiter.

I want to find a solution where the formatting of the original as shown in the photo can be preserved when using something similar to a VLOOKUP.

I've tried code online from https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/create-multi-select-dropdown-excel/ but it didn't seem to work and still produced the same result. I have also searched for non-VBA options, but it seems that the only way to automate the process would be to use VBA.

[Original Cell I want to be copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSmKS.png)

[What happens when I use a generic VLOOKUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOziS.png)

Comment: If you're using vlookup to return the value of one of these "multi-choice" cells then why not format the cell with the formula as "wrap text"?

Comment: I need each option that was selected to be on a different line and with the exact same formatting as the original cell it was copied from and "wrap text" sadly doesn't accomplish this

Comment: Then it seems like the posted code is not really relevant here? - this is more a question about vlookup.

Comment: I posted the code so that people could see how the multi-select dropdown is being created and how it is formatted in case that would be helpful information.

Comment: But the bottom line is you have a cell which may contain lines of text separated by `vbCrLf` - that's the only really relevant part.  My comment was not intended as a criticism - just to point out that folks here may focus on the code you've posted instead of the actual problem you have.

Comment: Might help to explain what other formatting (apart from the newlines) you have that needs to be carried over, and to add some examples of the VLOOKUP you're using.